# script - different time showing different content

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am trying to develop a website which displaying content follow the time of the user when they surfing on it.
For example, when morning time, the user will see a morning scene content,
while at night time, the user will see a good-night content.
How this can be done?
I don't know what this should be call. 
Anyone familiar with this please help 
Thank you

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
var hour = new Date().getHours();
if (hour < 10){
  // morning
  $('body').addClass("morning");
} else if (hour > 16){
  // evening
  $('body').addClass("evening");
}

// Check once every hour
setInterval(function(){
  // Remove all existing classes
  $('body').removeClass("morning evening");

  var hour = new Date().getHours();

  // Add back specific classes based on the hour
  if (hour < 10){
        // morning
        $('body').addClass("morning");
  } else if (hour > 16){
       // evening
       $('body').addClass("evening");
  }         
  }, 60000 );

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body.morning #background{
  background: url(images/morning.jpg);
  colour: blue;
}
body.evening #background{
   background: url(images/evening.jpg);
   colour: red;
}
</style>
```

while on html part:

```
<body>
<div id="background"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please show what you have attempted. This is a simple matter of checking the hour of the current time.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Not an expert on this script thing. But your answer made my day! I will try it tonight and see whether I can make it work or not.

Comment: If not, please do come back with an example of your code and HTML (good way to avoid down-votes here) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Just tried, seems fail. I not good in this script thing. Now figuring how to post the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check the hour of the current date/time and test that value for ranges. Based on those checks, add a class to the body and do the rest in your *cascading* style sheet (CSS).

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
if (hour < 10){
    // morning
    $('body').addClass("morning");
} else if (hour > 16){
    // evening
    $('body').addClass("evening");
}
```

etc

**Styling example**

```
body.morning #background{
     background: url(images/morning.jpg)
     colour: blue;
}
body.evening #background{
     background: url(images/evening.jpg)
     colour: red;
}
```

If you run this check on a regular basis (a slow setInterval), you could get live dynamic changes as the day moves between `morning => lunch => evening` etc. That would look pretty cool :)

e.g. something like

```
// Check once every hour
setInterval(function(){
    // Remove all existing classes
    $('body').removeClass("morning evening");

    var hour = new Date().getHours();

    // Add back specific classes based on the hour
    if (hour < 10){
        // morning
        $('body').addClass("morning");
    } else if (hour > 16){
        // evening
        $('body').addClass("evening");
    }         
}, 60000 );
```

Comment: This would be the best and most elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could load a different CSS based on the time of day, for example, if you have `day.css` and `night.css`, you could do something like this:

```
<script>
<!--
function getCSS() {
      var currentTime = new Date().getHours();

      if (7 <= currentTime && currentTime < 20) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='day.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      else
      {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='night.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
}

getCSS();
-->
</script>
```

Comment: Surely adding a single class to `body` would be enough for a CSS solution?

Comment: It would, but maybe its not just the body that needs to be altered, but rather the whole CSS set?

Comment: Hence *cascading* the style e.g. `body.morning .someclass`. It's called CSS for a reason :)

Comment: Well, you are right, but I like the decoupling that my solution offers.  Of course this depends on how radically different those two themes are...

Comment: Decoupling by separate CSS files does not allow things like dynamic changing (e.g. when morning turns into lunchtime, into evening). Now that would look cool :)

Comment: I can't argue with that :) ... although there are methods that allow for this i believe (maybe [like so](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-change-css-file-2/)?)

Comment: I am a big fan of K.I.S.S. Never over-complicate things *unless you absolutely have to*. It *sounds like* they just want to change a background and some colours, so a single CSS would be very efficient. Not saying your solution is wrong at all, just saying it can be done simpler :)

Comment: Agreed. /filling the min limit/